# When to use opensearch-spark versus opensearch-hadoop?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, opensearch

I need to read and write to OpenSearch from Spark (Azure Databricks). I can use either SparkSQL, Scala, or Pyspark (but not Java due to Databricks limitations). I got it working using two separate packages, [opensearch-hadoop](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-hadoop) and [opensearch-spark](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-spark/tree/main).

I can tell the 2 packages are meant for different things, based on their high level descriptions:

- OpenSearch Hadoop: "OpenSearch real-time search and analytics natively integrated with Hadoop. Supports Map/Reduce, Apache Hive, Apache Spark."
- OpenSearch Spark: "Spark Accelerator framework; It enables secondary indices to remote data stores."

However I don't know what that translates to practically. When would I want to use each of those?
Is one faster than the other for standard dataframe read & writes? Are there tradeoffs in functionality that I should know about?

Comment: You need to: 1. Ingest data from Spark to OpenSearch; 2. Query this data from OpenSearch for downstream services. Right?

Comment: Yes @Bondarenko

Answer (score 0):

I've set up OpenSearch with Databricks (on AWS) reading data from a Delta table streaming pipeline:

Delta table → PySpark DataFrame → Python transformation → OpenSearch REST API

It powers the search for a front end app, and seems to work pretty well. You'd probably want to use an Azure service principle with access to OpenSearch to make calls to the OpenSearch REST API.

A few issues were resolved along the way, but It usually runs fine without issue.  OpenSearch will usually index anything you throw at it, but defining the mappings in your index is probably a good idea though.

Comment: Which opensearch library did you use on your databricks cluster?

Comment: I started off using OpenSearch-py, which was OK initially. Later I used the REST API.